# Check the existence of partial derivatives and continuity of $f(x,y)$ at $(1,0)$ : $f(x,y) = \frac{3y(x-1)} {{({x-1})^2} +y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, partial-derivative

Check the existence of partial derivatives and continuity of $f(x,y)$ at $(1,0)$ : $f(x,y) = \frac{3y(x-1)} {{({x-1})^2} +y^2}$ when $(x,y)\neq (1,0)$ and $0$ otherwise. I decided to check continuity first - I calculated limit by considering different paths of approach and I got $0$ in all cases (confirmed continuity). I checked that in Wolfram and found out that limit shouldn't exist. Where have I done mistake and how to check the existence of partial derivatives?

Comment: Showing us the calculation you did can help.

Comment: To prove that a function is continuous, you can't just show that it is continuous along *some* paths.  Rather, you would have to show that it is continuous along *all* paths.  Usually, one does not show continuity in this manner–working along paths is typically more useful for showing that something is **not** continuous.  That being said, this function is not continuous at $(1,0)$.  You might consider lines of slope $\pm 1$ through that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x=y+1$, then$$f(x,y)=\frac{3y^2}{2y^2}=\frac32$$and that therefore if you approach $(1,0)$ along the line $x=y+1$, then the limit is $\frac32\neq0$.

Comment: Oh, I used $y=x$. So we know function is not continous at $(1,0)$, what’s then?

Comment: Note that $(1,0)$ does not belong to the line $y=x$. But the partial derivatives exist at $(1,0)$: they are both equal to $0$.

Comment: What about partial derivatives at $\neq(1,0)$

Comment: Outside $(1,0)$, that function is the quotient of two functions where the denominator has no zeros. So, the partial derivatives exist at any $(x,y)\neq(1,0)$.